# How do I evaluate a clustering performance if number of the clusters are not equal to ground truth labels?

Tags: image, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have been trying to learn unsupervised machine learning models.
I wanted to know if the number of predicted clusters are more or less than the number of ground truth labels, then how do we calculaate the accuracy. Is there any specific metrics to address this discrepancy?

I have tried k-means with silhhoutte. I have a medical image with 5 labels, but the algorithm returns 4 labels.

Answer (score 0):

When the number of clusters is not known or predetermined, evaluating clustering performance becomes more challenging. There are several methods you can use to evaluate clustering performance in such cases:

```
Internal Evaluation Metrics: Internal evaluation metrics assess the quality of the clustering based on the data itself, without relying on external information or the true number of clusters. Examples of internal evaluation metrics include the Silhouette coefficient, Davies-Bouldin index, Calinski-Harabasz index, and Dunn index. These metrics provide a measure of compactness, separation, or overall clustering quality.

External Evaluation Metrics: External evaluation metrics compare the clustering results with some external reference, such as known class labels if available. However, these metrics are not suitable when the number of clusters is not equal to the number of classes. If you have class labels, you could consider transforming the clustering results into a classification problem by assigning cluster labels to the data points and then use traditional classification evaluation metrics such as accuracy, precision, recall, or F1 score.

Stability-based Methods: Stability-based methods evaluate clustering stability by assessing the consistency of clustering results across multiple iterations or subsets of the data. Techniques like stability index, bootstrapping, or consensus clustering can provide insights into the robustness of the clustering algorithm and help determine the optimal number of clusters.

Visual Inspection: Visual inspection can be a useful approach to evaluate clustering results. Plotting the data points in a low-dimensional space using dimensionality reduction techniques (e.g., t-SNE, PCA) and coloring the points according to the clustering results can provide an intuitive visualization of the clusters. However, this method is subjective and might not provide a quantitative measure of performance.
```

It's important to note that clustering evaluation is a challenging problem, especially when the number of clusters is unknown or different from the ground truth. Different evaluation methods have their strengths and limitations, so it's advisable to use a combination of approaches and consider the specific characteristics and goals of your dataset and clustering task.